# Using concentrated sulfuric or nitric acid during titration of permanganate with oxalic acid

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry, titration

During titration of $\ce{KMnO4}$ with $\ce{H2C2O4}$, can we use concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{HNO3}$ instead of bench sulfuric acid?

Comment: Concentrated acids are never used for titration due to fluctuations in density/concentration and, most importantly, you are always going to greatly overshoot the equivalence point.

Comment: @AdityaJain We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field due to issues it gives rise to; see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. It is also preferable to avoid abbreviations and spell out chemical names in title. As for your answer, plagiarisms are not tolerated on Chemistry.SE. If you are using third-party sources (text/graphics/data), always make sure to distinctly separate quoted material (e.g. with `>` markup) from your work and put a proper reference.

Comment: Also, conc. $\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3]$ are oxidisers themselves and would, thus, confound the result.

Comment: And you **really** don't want to pour concentrated sulfuric acid into anything, due to heating, and both acids pose too much of a danger for casual use in titration.